# Google Cloud: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've looked at all similar questions and followed their advice but still getting this ClassNotFoundException. I'm running from the app engine on the Google Cloud and trying to access my cloud-based database instance which is in the same project. My app's WAR has deployed on the tomcat instance ok. I can get as far as the login screen so I know it's there. The stacktrace occurs as soon as I do anything that invokes my DAO class (see below for code). The database is successfully deployed and can be accessed from the MySQL workbench.

Here is my appengine-web.xml file exactly as is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>coop-140610</application>
    <version>0.9</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url"
            value="jdbc:google:mysql://coop-140610:asia-east1:coop/coop?user=root&amp;password=admin" />
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.local-database-url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/coop?user=root&amp;PASSWORD=admin&amp;useSSL=false" />
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

In my DAO class, I'm running this code:

```
   try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://coop-140610:asia-east1:coop?user=root";

            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            String sql = "select * from coop.user order by username";

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

In my project I have the jdbc connector library mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar

I'm at my wits end. I've checked and rechecked everything several dozen times. I'd be very grateful if someone can spot my mistake. Thank you.

Here's a possible clue... If I run this code in one of my bean getters:

```
  if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
            env = "Production";
        } else {
            env = "Development";
        }
  return env;
```

it returns 'Development'. Does this mean that my app has not been deployed properly? I deployed it by uploading the WAR via the tomcat manager.

Comment: App Engine standard or flex?

Comment: App Engine Standard

Comment: To clarify, are you getting this error locally or when you deploy?

Comment: It's after deployment. I can access simple pages that don't involve any data access but as soon as I invoke a page that uses the DAO then I get the error.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error you are getting into your question?

Comment: I get:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)

Comment: you should deploy using mvn appengine:update